# UI Component Grid not showing items

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I'm at the end of my chain.  I've tried rewriting the UI Component, I've played with the DataProvider, etc, etc and I just can't find any combination in which this works.

I've written previous grids that show items, but this one just refuses to.

For example:

[image]

Most curiously here is the "records found" text.  Not "0 records found", but just a number-less complete lack.

There are no errors in my logs or my JavaScript console - just a complete lack of items in my grid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">organization_listing.data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">organization_listing.data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">organization_listing_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Organization</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Briteskies\Organizations\Ui\DataProvider\Organizations\Grid\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="edit">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                        <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">organization_listing.organization_listing.column_editor</item>
                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="status">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change status</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <argument name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="organizations/index/massStatus">
                            <param name="status">1</param>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="organizations/index/massStatus">
                            <param name="status">2</param>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="organization_listing_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">organization_listing.organization_listing.organization_listing_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="charmoption/index/inlineEdit"/>
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">organization_listing.organization_listing.column_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="increment_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="customer_group_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Group</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">300</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="is_active">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">800</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

My first thought was, of course, there must be something wrong with the DataProvider.  But it's pretty difficult to mess up a DataProvider.

```
<?php

// namespaces

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    /** @var CollectionFactory */
    protected $collection;

    /** @var PoolInterface */
    protected $modifiers;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $organizationCollection,
        PoolInterface $modifierPool,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->modifiers = $modifierPool;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->collection = $organizationCollection->create();
    }

    public function getMeta()
    {
        $meta = parent::getMeta();

        foreach ($this->modifiers->getModifiersInstances() as $modifier) {
            $meta = $modifier->modifyMeta($meta);
        }

        return $meta;
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        $data = parent::getData();

        foreach ($this->modifiers->getModifiersInstances() as $modifier) {
            $data = $modifier->modifyData($data);
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Even removing the Pool modifier (getData() getMeta()) methods, we have the same result - so it can't be that - plus, I tested it as a command line function:

```
<?php

// namespaces

class Test extends Command
{
    protected $dp;

    public function __construct(DataProviderFactory $dp, $name = 'darley:test')
    {
        $this->dp = $dp->create([
            'name'             => 'test',
            'primaryFieldName' => 'entity_id',
            'requestFieldName' => 'entity_id',
            'data'             => [
                'config' => [
                    'component'     => 'Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider',
                    'update_url'    => 'mui/index/render',
                    'storageConfig' => [
                        'indexField' => 'entity_id',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('Count: '.$this->dp->count());
        var_dump($this->dp->getData());
    }
}
```

Which of course, works fine:

[image]

So I've just run out of ways to figure out why the Grid isn't loading in any data.

Why would a grid do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to the problem here is the output of the collection's `->toArray` method.  While it contains the entities desired, it does not contain them in the right format.

A typical flat table structure collection WILL output the expected array structure in Magento 2.1 - however, an *EAV Collection* will not.

In order to fix this grid, I had to add new keys to the top level of the resulting array.

```
    $data = [
        'totalRecords' => $this->getCollection()->getSize(),
        'items'        => array_values($this->getCollection()->toArray()),
    ];
```

With this structure, the grid rendered out as expected.

Please note that `array_values` may be necessary if the array is associative and your grid has select boxes.

Comment: Amazing worked perfectly for me! Thank you.

Comment: That saved my Hours of Debugging! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can see module_cms as your example

In etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="data_source" xsi:type="string">Namespace\YourModule\Model\ResourceModel\Organizations\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Connect your data_source with your resourcemodel

```
<type name="Namespace\YourModule\Model\ResourceModel\Organizations\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">db_table_name</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">your_prefix_name</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">your_event_name</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Organizations</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Namespace\YourModule\Model\ResourceModel\Organizations\Grid\Collection
Main content will be

```
/**
 * @var AggregationInterface
 */
protected $aggregations;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool
 * @param mixed|null $mainTable
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $eventPrefix
 * @param mixed $eventObject
 * @param mixed $resourceModel
 * @param string $model
 * @param null $connection
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb|null $resource
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool $metadataPool,
    $mainTable,
    $eventPrefix,
    $eventObject,
    $resourceModel,
    $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
    $connection = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $entityFactory,
        $logger,
        $fetchStrategy,
        $eventManager,
        $storeManager,
        $metadataPool,
        $connection,
        $resource
    );
    $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
    $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
    $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
    $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
}

/**
 * @return AggregationInterface
 */
public function getAggregations()
{
    return $this->aggregations;
}

/**
 * @param AggregationInterface $aggregations
 * @return $this
 */
public function setAggregations($aggregations)
{
    $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
}

/**
 * Get search criteria.
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
 */
public function getSearchCriteria()
{
    return null;
}

/**
 * Set search criteria.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
 * @return $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
{
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get total count.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getTotalCount()
{
    return $this->getSize();
}

/**
 * Set total count.
 *
 * @param int $totalCount
 * @return $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
{
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set items list.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
 * @return $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function setItems(array $items = null)
{
    return $this;
}
```

Don't forget flush cache after change code